# Alter schema on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema, alter

Sorry that this post is so long, for such a straight-forward issue. I've been working on this now for almost 3 days, and it's driving me totally crazy, so I'm trying to put as much detail here as I possibly can so that someone might be able to get me out of this nightmare!

I basically have two SQL Server 2008 R2 database back-up files from a shared host: `database-1.bak` and `database-2.bak`. Each of these databases were set up on different shared hosting accounts on the same shared server with one database user each (named 'database-1' and 'database-2' accordingly). The structure of the databases is identical, but the data isn't. `Database-1` has content, `database-2` is empty. I want to copy all data from `database-1` to `database-2` and then re-upload `database-2` back to the shared host. The two databases should then be exactly the same, but `database-1` should be owned by `database-1` schema and `database-2` by the `database-2` schema.

I've logged into SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 R2 as `sa` and restored these databases, so in there I now have two databases, one with a load of tables called e.g. `database-1.tblTest`, `database-1.tblTest2` etc; and the other with a load of tables called e.g. `database-2.tblTest`, `database-2.tblTest2` etc. So all of the tables in `database-1` are 'owned' by the `database-1` schema (the table names are prepended with `database-1.`) and all of the tables in `database-2` are 'owned' by the `database-2` schema (the table names are prepended with `database-2.`).

I've tried right-clicking `database-1` and selecting `Tasks > Export Data` and exporting it to `database-2`. The odd thing about this is that when it automatically maps the objects for exporting, it does this:

```
database-1.tblTest (on 'source' database-1) -> database-1.tblTest (on 'destination' database-2).
```

That's odd, because I would hope that it would do this instead:

```
database-1.tblTest (on 'source' database-1) -> database-2.tblTest (on 'destination' database-2).
```

I would hope that the tables in database-2 would keep their `database-2.` owner. If I map each of the tables like this:

```
database-1.tblTest -> database-2.tblTest
```

The export fails. If I keep the mapping as default (`database-1.tblTest -> database-1.tblTest`) it succeeds, but I then have a whole load of tables in `database-2` which are owned by the `database-1` schema.

This is now where I'm at. `Database-1` is the same as it was when I restored it. But `database-2` now has a set of tables prepended by `database-2.` and the same set of tables prepended by `database-1.`.

This is a problem because when I try to re-upload `database-2` back to the host server it errors because the schema is trying using `database-1` which is on the same server but a different account. So I need the tables in `database-2` to maintain their `database-2` schema owner but just be filled with the data from `database-1`.

I've tried running a query like this to try to change the schema on my imported tables in `database-2` from `database-1` to `database-2`:

```
USE [database-2]
ALTER SCHEMA [database-2] TRANSFER [database-1.tblTest]
```

However, this just errors:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot find the object 'database-1.tableTest', because it
>   does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

I'm logged into Management studio as `sa` throughout, so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Can anyone please shed any light on how to just get this data into `database-2` and keep the schema owner the same?

Any help would be massively appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is just a little off... because you enclose schema + table in a single square bracket, it assumed you had a table name with a period *and* a dash in it. Try this one:

```
ALTER SCHEMA [database-2] TRANSFER [database-1].[tblTest];
```

Strongly recommend staying away from dashes in database, schema, object and column names. Using them makes square brackets necessary and can complicate a lot of other tools and scripts that aren't expecting them.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I'm keen to try this out.  However, I'm in a bit of a pickle because in database-2 I have two sets of all of the tables now, so I really need to remove all the old empty ones (prepended by 'database-2.' and then run the alter script on the ones which were imported from database-1.  However, there are loads of tables in here (like, more than 100) and I can't seem to delete them because they all have different dependencies.  Is it just a case of keeping trying to delete them one by one until they're all gone, or is there a better way?

Comment: You could build a script from the catalog views (e.g. sys.foreign_keys) to drop all the dependencies first. Sounds like a different question, though.

Comment: Awesome - I just ran: EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?" several times and it deleted all of the tables it could each time until there were none left.  I tried your ALTER SCHEMA code and it worked perfectly, and it looks like the database has even uploaded correctly back to the server!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Pity, I had put together a script that would first drop all FKs pointing to any table in a specified schema, then drop the tables, in one shot - so that you don't have to run it over and over again until there are no more errors.

PS You didn't specify the schema in your DROP TABLE command?

Comment: That script would still be really handy in case this happens again.  I didn't realise the drop table needed a schema to be specified - I just put 'USE [database-2]' at the top and it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @Dan, I put it in a blog post, seemed a little too involved for a comment or even as an extension of this answer: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/07/07/using-the-catalog-views-clearing-out-a-botched-schema.aspx